# Length of array always zero in C# Unity

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a basic tic tac toe game using unity game engine. Here's my code :

```
public int[] board = new int[9] {
    0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0
};
public bool xTurn = true;

public void OnGUI() {
    float width = 75;
    float height = 75;
    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
        Debug.Log("Value of y = " + y);
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            Debug.Log("Length of array = " + board.Length);
            int boardIndex = (y * 3) + x;
            Rect square = new Rect(x * width, y * height, width, height);
            Debug.Log ("Value of boardIndex = " + boardIndex + " value of x = " + x);
            string owner = board[boardIndex] == 1 ? "X" :
                board[boardIndex] == -1 ? "O" : "";
            if(GUI.Button(square, owner))
                SetControl(boardIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that the length of `board` array is always 0 and getting a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception when trying to access any value inside the `board` array.
I've even tried different ways of creating the array. still the same result. Can anyone tell me the reason for length of array being 0.

Comment: pperhaps your code populating the array is not getting run?  Make sure that code is inside of a method that gets run (verify with breakpoints) and once you are sure that code is being hit, you should be good.

Comment: I believe you can initialize with public int[] board = { x, x, x }; Perhaps try initializing it differently

Comment: @RyPope: The initialization looks OK to me.  He would be getting a compile error otherwise.

Comment: @RyPope both syntaxes should work.

Comment: There is something you're not showing. As is, there is no way `board` would be `0` length.

Comment: are you calling any other methods inbetween which will access/modify the `board` array?

Comment: @Rotem There is a Debug.Log statement inside the second for loop. There I'm getting the length of array to be zero.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi No. This is the doc of OnGui() Method : https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html

Comment: @omerjerk I mean, either there's more code, or as McAden suggests, Unity is bugged.

Comment: by using Console.WriteLine, I get the **Length of array = 9**. Don't know where is problem and can't see where updating the board array..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've run into this with Unity before on public fields. I've speculated that it's due to how the editor interface integrates with public fields (editor is clearing your intialized value) but I haven't been able to find documentation to back that up. I have, however, been able to work around this by moving the initialization code into the `Start` function.

However, you may have to add extra logic if you still want this exposed within the editor.

```
void Start ()
{
    board = board ?? new int[9] {
      0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0
    };
}
```

Alternatively I think if you simply change the variable to `private` or `protected` that should remove it from the editor and it should also work.

Comment: My recollection is that Unity requires you to put almost all initialization in the Start method for MonoBehaviors as the constructor is not used to instantiate behaviors.

Comment: @omerjerk If you don't need to expose the `board` to the editor, you should just make it `private`